# Position elements proportional to superview when animating in Xcode playground

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, uiviewanimation, swift-playground

I am trying to position view elements in an UIImageView, and then animate the width of the UIImageView to fill the superview. I am using autolayout constraints to position and animate the views. At the beginning of the animation, the circle is positioned exactly at half of the centerX of the superView:

`self.circleXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.circle, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.bodyView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)`

But as the animation starts, the circle drifts away from the correct position (where the two lines cross).

I have used a couple of days trying to find out why the autolayout doesn't keep the circle view positioned correctly, but am unable to find out why.

[image: Body Animation]

The full code of the Xcode playground can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/imyrvold/Animate-body

Xcode Playground swift code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController : UIViewController {

lazy var bodyView: UIImageView = {
    let bodyView = UIImageView()
    bodyView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    bodyView.image = self.image
    bodyView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    return bodyView
}()
lazy var image: UIImage? = {
    UIImage(named: "body")
}()
lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    button.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(headZoom), for: .touchDown)
    button.titleLabel?.textColor = .black
    button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    return button
}()
lazy var circle: BodyAreaView = {
    let circle = BodyAreaView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 48, height: 48))
    circle.backgroundColor = .clear

    return circle
}()
// bodyView constraints
var topAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var centerXAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var aspectConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var superWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var iphoneHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var iphoneWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

// circle constraints
var circleHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var circleXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var circleYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var circleAspectConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view = view

    view.addSubview(self.bodyView)
    self.bodyView.addSubview(self.circle)
    view.addSubview(self.button)
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.setBodyViewConstraints()
    self.setFibroConstraints()

    self.bodyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.circle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.topAnchorConstraint,
        self.centerXAnchorConstraint,
        self.aspectConstraint,
        self.iphoneWidthConstraint
        ])

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.circleHeightConstraint,
        self.circleXConstraint,
        self.circleYConstraint,
        self.circleAspectConstraint
        ])
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}

@objc func headZoom() {
    self.superWidthConstraint.isActive = true
    print("body view before: \(self.bodyView.bounds)")
    print("circle origin before: \(self.circle.frame.origin)")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { _ in
        print("body view after: \(self.bodyView.bounds)")
        print("circle frame after: \(self.circle.frame)")
    }
}

func setBodyViewConstraints() {
    self.topAnchorConstraint = self.bodyView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor)
    self.centerXAnchorConstraint = self.bodyView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor)
    self.aspectConstraint = self.bodyView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bodyView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1388/408.0)
    self.superWidthConstraint = self.bodyView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1)
    self.iphoneHeightConstraint = self.bodyView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 633)
    self.iphoneWidthConstraint = self.bodyView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 186)
}

func setFibroConstraints() {
    self.circleHeightConstraint = self.circle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bodyView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.05)
    self.circleXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.circle, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.bodyView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
    self.circleYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.circle, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.bodyView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
    self.circleAspectConstraint = self.circle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.circle.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1)
}

}

let viewController = ViewController()
viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 812)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

I have updated the Xcode playground, and it will now show the background of the circle view in the .cyan color, as suggested.

It sounded like an easy task to just update the drawing code of the UIView subclass, but after a few hours searching for solutions here on stack overflow, none of the posts did any help. It looks like the circle refuses to redraw itself, even as the bounds of the view itself changes.

I simplified the UIView subclass code, for easier understanding how the drawing works. I would love getting any help for this. Many of the posts I have looked at suggests overriding layoutSubviews, setting the sublayers frame to the views layer bounds, but that doesn't work in this case. Must be something I have overlooked.

Here is the code for the BodyAreaView, reduced to just drawing the circle ring:

```
import UIKit

public class BodyAreaView: UIView {
var ringColor: UIColor = .black

lazy var ringLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
    let ringLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let ringPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4, dy: 4))
    ringLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    ringLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    ringLayer.path = ringPath.cgPath
    ringLayer.name = "ring"
    ringLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true

    return ringLayer
}()

override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.layer.addSublayer(self.ringLayer)
}

override public func layoutSubviews() {
    guard let sublayers = self.layer.sublayers else { return }
    for layer in sublayers {
        layer.frame = layer.bounds
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Your subview ***is*** resizing correctly - the problem is that your code to draw the "ring" is not accounting for it. Change the background from clear to a color... `circle.backgroundColor = .cyan`, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Yes, of course. I see it now. I have blindly looked at the viewController animation of the constraints, and overlooked how the circle is drawn inside the BodyAreaView. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the Xcode playground, simplifying the code. I still haven't found a solution for redrawing the circle to fill the bounds of the view after the animation. I don't need to have the circle drawing animated, just need to have it redrawn after the animation have completed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Constraint Conflict

First of all, you're not taking into account that layout can occur many times. So in your `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()` you are reactivating the same constraints over and over again. This means that when you say

```
    self.superWidthConstraint.isActive = true
```

you are getting a *constraint conflict*, because your `iphoneWidthConstraint` is still active: you are asking for *both* the old width constraint *and* the new width constraint. The fact that you are seeing any width change at all is thus sheer luck.

The solution to that is as follows. First, write your `layout` code with a flag so that you initialize everything only once:

```
var didInitialLayout = false
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if didInitialLayout { return } // *
    didInitialLayout = true //
    // ...
```

Second, deactivate the old width constraint before you activate the new one:

```
@objc func headZoom() {
    self.iphoneWidthConstraint.isActive = false // *
    self.superWidthConstraint.isActive = true
    // ...
```

Okay, now the conflict is gone.

#### Drawing the Circle

So now we are free to concentrate on the drawing code! That code (your BodyAreaView) has so many issues that I'm not sure where to start. But, to summarise:

```
override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.layer.addSublayer(self.ringLayer)
}
```

Here we have the classic mistake of a `draw` where you don't draw. Instead, you do something else totally irrelevant: you add a layer. That's always dangerous because `draw` can be called many times; in a worst case scenario you could end up adding this layer over and over again. (Here, that's probably not happening, but again that's just luck.)

Next:

```
override public func layoutSubviews() {
```

You seem to think you're going to get that message multiple times during the animation. You're not. Also you're forgetting to call `super` which can be disastrous.

And finally, your use of a shape layer:

```
lazy var ringLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
    let ringLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let ringPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4, dy: 4))
    ringLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    ringLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    ringLayer.path = ringPath.cgPath
    ringLayer.name = "ring"
    ringLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true

    return ringLayer
}()
```

First of all, your layer has no frame and hence no size. Second, this code will run *only once*. So you will get one path, once, and then nothing will ever happen that will change the size of the path. The `ringPath` radius is not magically somehow tied forever to the size of the view as it changes. It is created at a certain size and that's that. That is why you do not in fact *see* the path ever change. (The use of `needsDisplayOnBoundsChange` is totally irrelevant, because you don't have a layer that does display! That would be a layer where *you* do the drawing, and that's not what you have.)

#### Drawing With a View

Okay, what's the simplest solution? What I would do in the first instance is throw away the layer entirely and just draw the circle:

```
public class BodyAreaView: UIView {
    override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let ringPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4, dy: 4))
        let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        con.addPath(ringPath.cgPath)
        con.strokePath()
    }
}
```

That works perfectly, because we draw *once* and from then on we use the cached circle drawing, which grows as the view grows. And if we *do* draw again, we will draw proportionately to the size of the view at the time, so the circle will always look correct.

#### Drawing With a Layer

Okay, but this doesn't really answer your original question, which is how to do this with a *layer*. Well, again, the answer is: don't use a shape layer, because that's not a self-redrawing layer. Do it with a *custom* layer that knows how to redraw itself as a circle based on its current bounds size. For example:

```
public class BodyAreaView: UIView {
    class Circle : CALayer {
        override func draw(in con: CGContext) {
            let ringPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4, dy: 4))
            con.addPath(ringPath.cgPath)
            con.strokePath()
        }
    }
    let circle = Circle()
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        self.circle.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
        self.circle.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.circle)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if let layers = self.layer.sublayers {
            for lay in layers {
                lay.frame = self.bounds
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Observe, however, that this causes the circle's size to *jump* at the start of the animation. It jumps to the right place, namely where the circle will need to be at the end of the animation. That's because you don't get autolayout animation for layers. That's why I prefer the first solution; at least there, the circle grows with the view.

But you *can* work around the problem, by *animating the layer size separately*. That is left as an exercise for the reader. :)